# Windows Phone Emulator Stuck at "OS is Loading" (VS 2017 Community)

Tags: c#, emulation, universal

So I am running VS Community 2017. Hypervisor is fully functional but after running Windows Phone emulators in a "Universal App" project, it gets stuck at the "Deploying" stage ("OS is Running" displayed on the emulator screen) and finally fails to load....Here's a screenshot:

[image]

and finally:

[image]

I would greatly appreciate any help...